# Get some tags through web scraping with selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

thank you for taking the time to read me, I hope write in a crearly and easy way. I'm new in python and selenium, I'm trying to crawl a web page linked https://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bosques-de-las-lomas-departamento-a-la-venta-en-bosque-62355654.html, and another similar link, a specification, is that I want to crawl more pages like this, but I'm trying to work with this. Now I'm having problems with scraping some tags, because there are some tags that are included in some pages but no in others. In this way, I want to crawl a list of tags that could include some webpage. Following, there is a piece of the view from the webpage where I show the tags circled in red.

[The image shows in red the tags I'm interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZtB.png)

So, I'm trying to crawl the tags with a function "for", "try" and "except" and after keep the information in different lists. The code is the following.

```
par2 = ['https://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bosques-de-las-lomas-departamento-a-la-venta-en-bosque-62355654.html',
       'https://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/tu-mejor-lugar-en-tulum-hyd-60498140.html']
links = []
titulo = []
sup_total = []
sup = ""
superficie_cons = []
cons_ = ""
baños = []
ban_ = ""

for pares in par2:
    pares2 = pares
    driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/driver/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(pares)
    sleep(random.uniform(1,4))
    
    tit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="section-title"]').text
    titulo.append(tit)
    
    links.append(pares2)
    
    etiquetas = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@class="icon-feature"]')
    
    for etiq in etiquetas:
        try:
            valores = etiq.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="icon feature"]').text.strip().lower()
            print(valores)
            
            if 'total' in valores:
                sup = valores
                
            if 'construido ' in valores:
                cons_ = valores
                
            if 'baños' in valores:
                ban_ = valores
                
        except:
            print('null')
            
    sup_total.append(sup)
    superficie_cons.append(cons_)
    baños.append(ban_)
    
    driver.quit()
```

My idea in general is that the code must download each tag if the page contains the tag. For example the first webpage has 7 tags, meanwhile the second link has 6 tags, thats the reason why I consider the name of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below and confirm:

```
driver.get("https://www.inmuebles24.com/propiedades/bosques-de-las-lomas-departamento-a-la-venta-en-bosque-62355654.html")
links = []
titulo = []
sup_total = []
sup = ""
superficie_cons = []
cons_ = ""
banos = []
ban_ = ""

title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[contains(@class,'article-section-description')]//h1").text
print(title)
features = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("icon-feature")

for feature in features:
    if 'Total' in feature.text:
        sup = feature.text

    if 'Construido' in feature.text:
        cons_ = feature.text

    if 'Baño' in feature.text:
        ban_ = feature.text

sup_total.append(sup)
superficie_cons.append(cons_)
banos.append(ban_)
print(sup_total)
print(superficie_cons)
print(banos)
```

```
Bosques de Las Lomas Departamento a La Venta en Bosque de Tejocotes (Ao)
['220 m² Total']
['220 m² Construido']
['3 Baños']
```